# clipboard manager extension for writer

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-writer, clipboardmanager

I am trying to build a clipboard manager extension for Libre office. When-ever I cut (or copy) text from a document, it should be appended to another file so that I will never loose my work even if I forget to paste it somewhere. Is it possible in libre office?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This chapter explains how to register a clipboard listener: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OfficeDev/Common_Application_Features

I wonder how your extension will handle when someone copies an image instead of text. Perhaps in that case you could catch an exception and end the call cleanly. Or perhaps you could determine that ahead of time, based on the mime type.

Comment: I will take care not to copy anything other than text (MimeType Unicode Text text/plain; charset=utf-16). The text needs to be pasted in clear text without any formatting. I checked some free / paid windows utilities. But I do not need a lot of features offered by commercial software. I am looking for a free and open source extension. Bounty for code contribution.